# Get page url from Link Field on a component using SessionAwareCoreServiceClient C#

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, c#

I have a link field and XML looks like the below. Using SessionAwareCoreServiceClient c#; I would like to get the page URL for "tcm:99-99999". "tcm:99-99999" is a component "Global EN\Building Blocks\Content\xyz" it seems. I am not sure how to get page links using the core service.

```
 <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:99-99999" xlink:title="TC Bakel - home" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
```

I have tried  like below but it is listing pages than what actual page

```
var filter = new UsingItemsFilterData
{
    ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Page },
    BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended
};

IEnumerable<PageData> usingPages = TridionServiceClient.Instance.GetClient().GetList(field.XlinkHref, filter).OfType<PageData>();
```

Comment: please update to tag the tridion sites version.

Answer (score 1):

This below solution only applies to the Topology manager setup with the view on-site feature introduced in Tridion Sites 8.0+,

For the component possibly used directly or indirectly to resolve multiple pages, you need to use the **ResolveContainingPages** core service method to return a set of pages where the component is directly or indirectly (via component links) used.

If page is published, the associated set of publish info is also returned (one **PublishInfoData** instance per publish destination).

```
ContainingPagesDictionary ResolveContainingPages(
    string componentId,
    ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData instruction
)
```

**Example:**

```
 ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData instruction = new ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData() {
        IncludeComponentMetadataLinks = true,
        IncludeDynamicVersion = true,
        IncludePageMetadataLinks = true,
        IncludeWorkflow = true,
        ResolvePublishedPagesOnly = true
    };

    ContainingPagesDictionary dictionary = Client.ResolveContainingPages("tcm:1135-11570", instruction);
  
    foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(k => k.Item.Title))
    {
        string publishUrl = Client.GetPublishUrl(key.Item.IdRef, "Staging");
        Console.WriteLine($"{key.Item.Title} ({key.Item.IdRef}) - {publishUrl}");
    }
```

**Updated:**

Tridion Sites 2013sp1 - it's already retired, I think you need to do this by recursively doing a 'Where used' on the Component until you get a list of Pages and then seeing whether they're published to get the page URLs.

Comment: ResolveContainingPages method is not present , I am using 7.1.0.1290 Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client dll

Comment: Ah, Tridion 2013SP1 is already retired still using it? I have updated my answer.

Comment: As the version number suggests... that's a 10 year old release :)